# What's the fastest way to get a random element from a tuple? (python)

Tags: python, tuples

Can you do better than this basic implementation:

```
import random
def get_random_element(_tuple):
    return _tuple[randint(0, len(_tuple) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> x = tuple(range(100))
>>> random.choice(x)
8
```

[random.choice](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice)

@Updated as asked by S. Lott:

```
def first(_tuple):
    return _tuple[randint(0, len(_tuple) - 1)]

def second(_tuple):
    return choice(_tuple)

print timeit('first(t)', 'from __main__ import first; t = tuple(range(10))')        
print timeit('second(t)', 'from __main__ import second; t = tuple(range(10))')
```

Output:

```
2.73662090302
1.01494002342
```

Comment: But is it faster?  Did you measure?  Can use you `timeit` to show which is faster?

Comment: you're better off using `random.randrange`

Comment: @SilentGhost: 2.4 for `random.randrange`.

Comment: @sukhbir: as in *don't use `randint` at all*, not as in *faster then `choice`*

Comment: Aah ok. You are right, using `random.randrange` makes more sense than `random.randint` for such a case (but not better than `random.choice` of course)

Answer (score 5):

Use random.choice: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice

Answer (score 3):

[random.choice()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
random.choice(_tuple)
```